# fwrite to txt-file

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm currently trying to write to a txt-file with PHP, I've found this small script:

```
<?php
$filename = 'testFile.txt';
$somecontent = "Add this to the file\n";

if (is_writable($filename)) {

    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";
    fclose($handle);

} 

else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
?>
```

I get a success-message, but nothing is written to the file. Even if I delete the txt-file I still get the success-message

Does anybody know how to troubleshoot a situation like this?

Comment: if you delete the file, is it recreated after you see the success message?

Comment: Also, try to "echo fwrite($handle, $somecontent)", it should print the number of bytes written.

Comment: The file is not recreated after the success-message.

When I "echo fwrite($handle, $somecontent)" I get 21 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly fine. However, note that the `is_writable` check will fail if the file does not exist yet.

If you execute it through a webserver, make sure you are not viewing a cached response.

Comment: (just thought of the response being cached myself)

Comment: I'm executing the script through a webserver - sorry for being a n00b but how do avoid viewing a cached response?

Comment: Send headers which prevent caching or, if it's just for you, you can just reload it with CTRL+F5

Answer (score 2):

Your first check with `is_writable` is not useful, as it fails if the file does not exist.
When you use `fopen` with the "a" parameter you appent to the file *if it exists* otherwise it will create a new one.

If you want to check if the file exists you can with `file_exists` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php ), but it is not really necessary.

With your code, if you delete the file you should actually get a "the file is not writable" error... are you sure you have *exactly* that code?

Otherwise, I tried the code and it works fine (without the first `if`).

Comment: The OP's code (including the `is_writable` check) is fronm the official `fwrite` example on php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php. Is their code incorrect?

Comment: @amindfv: it is not technically incorrect, but it is using `is_writable` to check existence of a file, which is not what the function should be used to. `is_writable` will indeed fail if the file does not exist, but this is not the desired behaviour here. So, yes, their code is "functionally incorrect".